# Date a String asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, date

Quiero imprimir en mi vista una fecha de esta manera: "28 de agosto de 2020" , por ejemplo.

En la vista solo tengo

```
<h4>@ViewBag.Fecha</h4>
<h4>@ViewBag.Fc</h4>
```

En mi controlador tengo

```
ViewBag.Fecha = Fechas._fecha_fin.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"); //Esto me trae "28 agosto 2020"
ViewBag.Fc = Fechas._fecha_fin.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("es-Es", true)); //Esto trae "viernes, 28 de agosto de 2020"
```

En la primera opción me falta la palabra "de" y en la segunda opción me sobra el día de la semana.
¿Como puedo hacer que solo traiga "28 de agosto de 2020" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tienes, solo agrega los 'de' faltantes en la cadena del format:

```
Fechas._fecha_fin.ToString("dd 'de' MMMM  'de' yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.Fecha = Fechas._fecha_fin.ToString("dd") & "de" & Fechas._fecha_fin.ToString("MMMM yyyy")
```

Comment: Cómo debería usar el OP tu respuesta. Procura siempre una pequeña explicación de cómo usar el código que se sugiere.